# Unique class instances in Python3

Tags: python, numpy, unique

suppose I have a class definition like this

```
class structure:
    def __init__(self, handle):
        self.handle = handle
```

How can I use `numpy.unique` or another tool of Python3 to find unique elements in a list of instances of this class? The comparison should be done with respect to the value of the `'handle'` field.

Comment: Do you want the values for handle, or the instances?  If you want the instances and two instances have same value for handle, which should be chosen?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`numpy.unique` is not the best tool for custom classes. Make your instances [hashable](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-hashable) (implementing [`__hash__`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__hash__) and [`__eq__`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__eq__)), then use a set to reduce a list of instances to unique values:

```
class structure:
    def __init__(self, handle):
        self.handle = handle

    def __hash__(self):
        return hash(self.handle)

    def __eq__(self, other):
        if not isinstance(other, structure):
            # only equality tests to other `structure` instances are supported
            return NotImplemented
        return self.handle == other.handle
```

Sets efficiently can detect duplicates via the hash, confirming that the objects with the same hash are also equal first.

To get the unique instances, simply call `set()` on a sequence of instances:

```
unique_structures = set(list_of_structures)
```

Demo:

```
>>> class structure:
...     def __init__(self, handle):
...         self.handle = handle
...     def __hash__(self):
...         return hash(self.handle)
...     def __eq__(self, other):
...         if not isinstance(other, structure):
...             # only equality tests to other `structure` instances are supported
...             return NotImplemented
...         return self.handle == other.handle
...     def __repr__(self):
...         return '<structure({!r})>'.format(self.handle)
...
>>> list_of_structures = [structure('foo'), structure('bar'), structure('foo'), structure('spam'), structure('spam')]
>>> set(list_of_structures)
{<structure('bar')>, <structure('foo')>, <structure('spam')>}
```

Do take into account that the hash of any `structure` instance stored in a set or used a dictionary key *must not change*; not altering the `handle` attribute during the lifetime of an instance is the easiest way to ensure this.

Comment: Could I ask you kindly to explaing the reason of insertion of 'if not isinstance'?

Comment: @Macaronnos: comparison methods like `__eq__` should always return `NotImplemented` for comparisons they do not support; there is little point in supporting equality tests with anything other than `structure` instances.

Comment: Oh, exactly. Thank you.

Comment: In the `__eq__` function, can you simply use `return hash(self) == hash(other)` given the `__hash__` function also being implemented?  If not, what would be the reason not to?

Comment: @iamdave hash values are not unique, two objects that have the same hash are not necessarily also equal. A set checks for equality if there is a hashing collision.